# How can I float some text to the right of the first line of a paragraph?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning

I'd like to put some right-aligned text on the first line of my paragraph, and have the rest of the text wrap around it, like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed      {right-aligned text}
do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean kind of like a `wrapfig`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`wrapfig` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{wrapfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand{\rtext}{O{1} O{5em} m}{%
  \begin{wrapfigure}[#1]{r}[0pt]{#2}%
    \begin{minipage}{#2}\raggedleft#3\end{minipage}%
  \end{wrapfigure}%
}
\rtext[5][50pt]{Here is some right-aligned text}%
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}​
```

[image]

The above code provides `\rtext[<lines>][<width>]{<stuff>}` that typesets `<stuff>` right-aligned (actually `\raggedleft`) in `<lines>` lines of width `<width>` (the default is `1` line with width `5em`, although this can be changed). Both `<lines>` and `<width>` are optional arguments.

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) was used with the option `showframe` to show the alignment of the text. [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided dummy text, while [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides an easy means for specifying mixed optional/mandatory arguments (and defaults).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make it automatically adjust the width to fit its contents?

Comment: Also, what's the point of the minipage? It seems to work without it.

Comment: You could try to use the [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) to adjust the width automatically based on the contents. The `minipage` was just to provide a box to put stuff in; I wasn't sure how much content you wanted in the `{right-aligned text}`.

Answer (score 0):

Also see both answers to [Float right aligned text around a text snippet in first line of a paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144279).
Wrapfig does not work well with `enumerate` and `itemize` while `\parshape` and birectional layout (e.g. `\luatextextdir` and `\beginR`) can both handle this case as well.